# How to control the display time of the message pop-up window

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use `this.$toast()` to remind user that the disk format is in progress,but message just show 1 second,I want message show untill formatting is done,what shall I do?

Comment: Have you considered using async/await?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$toast("I'm a toast!", {
  timeout: 5000,
});
```